# How to Recduce the Character Length of WordPress Post Title

Tags: wordpress, post, title

I want to limit the characters of post title in WordPress.

Suppose I have published an article with 150 characters post title but I want to show only 120 characters. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply edit the header of your theme in `wp-content/themes/your-theme/header.php`. Then change the title depending on the number of characters:

```
<title><?php
    $title = wp_title(' - ', false, 'right');
    if (strlen($title) > 120) $title = substr($title, 0, 117) . "...";
    echo $title;
?></title>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is best in this regards I used this. This site explain 5 ways for reducing:

http://www.doc4design.com/articles/wordpress-5ways-shorten-titles/

Comment: Please, format your answer as a link and regular text and provide summary of the linked page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php echo $blogUrl; ?>?p=<?php echo the_ID(); ?>">
<?php 
    if (strlen($post->post_title) > 120) {
        echo substr(the_title($before = '', $after = '', FALSE), 0, 120) . '...'; 
    } else {
        the_title();
    } 
?>
</a>
```